# Selection Sort in ArrayList of Integers w/o Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting

I need to code my own method selection sort WITHOUT the Collections.sort() in Java. This is my current code, and I can't seem to figure out how to actually swap positions in the list. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

```
        ArrayList<Integer> ListOfNumbers = new ArrayList(8);

        ListOfNumbers.add(9);
        ListOfNumbers.add(19);
        ListOfNumbers.add(2);
        ListOfNumbers.add(1231);
        ListOfNumbers.add(89);
        ListOfNumbers.add(17);
        ListOfNumbers.add(3);
        ListOfNumbers.add(1);

        for(int i=0; i<ListOfNumbers.size(); i++)
        {
          int CurrentMinimum = i;

          for (int j=i+1; j<ListOfNumbers.size(); j++)
          {
            if(ListOfNumbers.get(j) < ListOfNumbers.get(i))
            {
              CurrentMinimum = j;   
            }
            if (CurrentMinimum != i)
            {
              int temp;
              temp = i;
              i = CurrentMinimum;
              CurrentMinimum = temp;
              System.out.println(ListOfNumbers);
            }                   
          }                     
        }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm (or https://www.youtube.com/user/AlgoRythmics/videos if you prefer some illustration :p)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the set method in List Interface to swap the values.

```
set(int index, E element)
```

Basically do the following:

```
int temp = list.get(i);
list.set(i, list.get(j));
list.set(j, temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Permute index a with index b in array list al :

1. temp = al.remove(a)
2. al.add(a, al.remove(b)) ////// updated
3. al.add(b,temp)

Hope it will help.

### EDIT1 : more precisely :

You have got a problem in your sort algorithm :

```
/* find the next minimum */
for(int j=i+1; j<ListOfNumbers.size(); j++)
{
    if(ListOfNumbers.get(j) < ListOfNumbers.get(CurrentMinimum)) // <<<<<
    {
         CurrentMinimum = j; 
    }
}
```

/* then, if necessary, permute */

```
temp = ListOfNumbers.remove(i);
ListOfNumbers.add(i, ListOfNumbers.remove(CurrentMinimum-1)); // -1 because of previous remove
ListOfNumbers.add(CurrentMinimum,temp);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can  use

```
 List<Integer> ListOfNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
Collections.swap(ListOfNumbers, 0, 3);
```